# TryParse return false for no reason

Tags: c#, .net, tryparse

I have a problem with a simple `TryParse` in Console Application.

Take a look:

```
string DepartureTimeString = Console.ReadLine(); // Enter 2015 01 11 22 45 30
// DepartureTimeString = 2015 01 11 22 45 30
string DepartureTimeStringTrim = DepartureTimeString.Replace(" ", "");
// DepartureTimeStringTrim = 20150111224530
Analyseur = int.TryParse(DepartureTimeStringTrim, out Resultat);
// Analyseur = false
```

The 'Analyseur' is false..
The string is 20150111224530.. It is just an int..
I had check with stop point the data in VS to be sure.

Where is the problem?

Comment: This looks like a date - is there a reason you are trying to parse it as an `int` instead of a `DateTime`?

Comment: Maybe I try hard for nothing... I just want to convert my string in a DateTime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maximum value you can store in `int` or `Int32` is [int.MaxValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or 2,147,483,647.

The value you are trying to store in a variable of type `int` is bigger than this value so the operation fail. 
You should use `long` or `Int64` for this value.

I see that you are trying to store a `DateTime` in `int`. It is not a good practice unless you have a good reason for doing that. you can use [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to convert the input into a `DateTime`. If you are using `int` as a container you can not be sure whether the user input is a valid date or not but using `DateTime` it is possible.

As [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284240/tim-schmelter) mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27892550/3970411) you can use `"yyyy MM dd HH mm ss"` as format string in `DateTime.TryParseExact` and parse the input value into a `DateTime`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And can I convert a string like my string into a DateTime without more step ?

Comment: Works : Analyseur = Int64.TryParse(DepartureTimeStringTrim, out Resultat64);

Answer (score 4):

That seems to be a `DateTime` instead of an int, so use `DateTime.TryParse`:

```
string departureString = "2015 01 11 22 45 30";
DateTime departure;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(departureString, "yyyy MM dd HH mm ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out departure))
    Console.Write("Departure at: " + departure.ToShortDateString());
```

The reason why it cannot be parsed to `int` is alrady [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27892524/284240), [`int`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kzh1b5w.aspx) cannot hold it(-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647), you need a larger data type like `long`.

Comment: Nice answer. I don't even know the DateTime.TryParseExact. Thanks it is powerful !

Answer (score 3):

Use Long instead of Int. Int is not that big.

Comment: I thought of that, but did not want to give the impression that "20150111224530" would directly parse to 2015-01-11 22:45:30.000